# Are $\varnothing$ and $\{\varnothing\}$ equal?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Are the sets $\varnothing$ and $\{\varnothing\}$ equal?

Comment: From the duplicate: > we can form the set $ \{ \emptyset \} $ whose only member is $\emptyset $. Note that $ \{ \emptyset \} \neq  \emptyset $, because $ \emptyset \in \{ \emptyset \} $ but $\underline{ \emptyset \notin \emptyset} $·

Comment: An empty bag is different from a bag containing an empty bag . . .

Comment: @NoahSchweber Nice. Quite clear.

Answer (score 3):

No!

$\emptyset$ is a set with no elements, $\{\emptyset\}$ is a set with one element.

Comment: What is wrong with this answer that justifies a downvote?